# How to merge two hashes of string arrays

Tags: ruby, merge, hashmap

How can I merge two hashes in the following conditions:

```
# 1º case
  a = {}
  b = { "1"=>["c1", "c2"], "2"=>["c2","c3"] }
  # merging a and b
# a = { "1"=>["c1", "c2"], "2"=>["c2","c3"] } 

# 2º case
  a = { "1"=>["c1", "c2"], "2"=>["c2","c3"] } 
  c = { "1"=>["c1", "c3"], "3"=>["c5"] }
  # merging a and c   
# a = { "1"=>["c1", "c2", "c3"], "2"=>["c2","c3"], "3"=>["c5"] }
```

What I got until now:

For arrays I know it is possible to merge with the operator "|"

```
a = ["c0", "c1"], b = ["c1", "c2"]
a = a | b
# a = ["c0", "c1", "c2"]
```

But with the hashes is not working:

```
a.merge(b){ |key, oldval, newval| oldval | newval }
# returns whatever was in the first place for the Hash a
```

There are answers in the S.O (actually one of them use the same example above), but I haven't been able to make it work (I also already try to merge with a non-empty hash). I know I could open then in a looping and etc... but I'm looking for the "rubish" way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a.merge(c){ |key, oldval, newval| oldval | newval }` works for your second case and similarly with `b` for your first.

Comment: Your solution works for me on 2.2.4p230 i386-mingw32.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.. I will re-check again tomorrow.

Comment: It's working. My mistake. I wasn't attributing the output to a new variable (as I thought the caller of merge would receive the output).